# Get indices of last N elements in each column of array A, but only those that are False in some mask M with same shape as A

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let `A` be the following array

```py
A = np.array([[2, 1, 2, 2],
              [1, 4, 0, 3],
              [0, 0, 3, 4],
              [3, 3, 1, 0],
              [4, 2, 4, 1]])
```

and let `M` be the following boolean mask

```
M = np.array([[ True, False, False, False],
              [ True, False, False, False],
              [False,  True, False,  True],
              [ True,  True, False, False],
              [False,  True,  True, False]])
```

Question 1:

How can I get the indices of the last N elements in each column of `A` such that they are `False` in the mask `M`?

In other words, I would like to get indices (for `N = 2`)

```
row_ixs = [2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4]
col_ixs = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Question 2:

How can I get the indices of the elements in each column of `A` that are not among the first N elements of A that are also `False` in the mask `M`?

In other words, I would like to get indices (for `N = 2`)

```
row_ixs = [2, 3, 3, 4]
col_ixs = [2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
M2 = ~M.T
M3 = M2[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)[:, ::-1] <= 2

col_ixs, row_ixs = np.where(M2&M3)
```

Output:

```
# col_ixs
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3])

# row_ixs
array([2, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

##### steps

```
# invert boolean values and transpose
M2 = ~M.T

array([[False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False,  True,  True]])

# get a reversed cumsum to identify the last N items
M2[:, ::-1].cumsum(axis=1)[:, ::-1]

array([[2, 2, 2, 1, 1],
       [2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [4, 3, 2, 1, 0],
       [4, 3, 2, 2, 1]])

# combine with original M2 to keep the last 2 True (with respect to M2)

array([[False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True]])
```

##### question #2

```
M2 = ~M.T
M3 = M2.cumsum(axis=1) > 2

col_ixs, row_ixs = np.where(M2&M3)
```

Output:

```
array([2, 2, 3, 3]), array([2, 3, 3, 4])
```

Comment: thanks @mozway for this black numpy magic. sorry i got the question wrong, and just changed it. i actually want to keep the first N elements in each column that are False in M, and i want the indices of all elements in each column that are not part of the first N elements that are False in M